# bokeh plot in jupyter is squeezed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am using the bokeh library to generate a graph, but the generated graph is not displayed correctly. It plots the graph but creates a scroll-bar so I cant see the entire graph:

[image]

My commands are pretty straightforward:

```
output_notebook()
src = ColumnDataSource(data= {})
p = figure()
p.line()
p.show()
```

I've used a multi-line plot before and that seems to work fine. I tried this on chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I found it.
`sizing_mode='stretch_both',`
doesn't work/is invalid in the notebook mode.

Comment: It should work with Bokeh >= 1.1 Before that version, results may vary. Also, for future reference, it is nearly impossible to help questions with this little information. In particular you should *always* provide all versions of relevant packages (e,g. Bokeh and the notebook, in this case)

Comment: @bigreddot thanks. I will keep that in mind for future questions